# Webdriver Wait showing StaleElementReferenceException Message Element is no longer valid when i loop through table rows

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Python.  I have some code which loops through rows in a HTML table.  It finds the values in the columns.
I am getting Element is no longer valid.
It is a race condition because sometimes it works if all the rows load in time on the webpage.

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer valid
```

I am using Webdriver Wait.  Maybe my syntax is incorrect.  Here is my code snippet.
It would be helpful if someone could give help here on how to solve this element no longer valid issue.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from Locators.locators import MainPageLocators

def is_mappings_details_saved(self, name, dataset, feed, variable):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'td')))
        table_id = self.get_element(*MainPageLocators.mappings_details_savedpage_table)
        #rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        rows = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")))
        for row in rows:
            time.sleep(1)
            # Get the columns
            col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]  # This is the Name column
            col_variable = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]  # This is the Variable column
            col_feed = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[3]  # This is the Feed column
            col_data_category = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[4]  # This is the Data Category column
            col_dataset = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[6]  # This is the Dataset column
            col_datamap = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[7]  # This is the Datamap column
            if (col_name.text == name) and (col_variable.text == variable) and (col_feed.text == feed) and (col_data_category.text == "Main") and (col_dataset.text == dataset) and (col_datamap.text == self.datamap_name):
                return True
        return False
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        return False
```

The following line is where the problem is

```
rows = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")))
```

The webpage displays a table of columns (Name, Variable, Feed etc).
Each row has data for each column.  E.g. Lucy, Name, datafeed.
I am checking if the data is correct in each row in the if statement.
I need to wait for all off the rows in the table to be loaded to avoid the stale element exception.
What is the best way to wait for the whole table to be loaded?

---

**Here is the working solution:**

JeffC suggested to wait for just the table container to load. No need to wait for cols and rows as well. I have got it to work now. I also put self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)in the base class.
Here is the working solution:

```
class BasePage(object):

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)

class MappingsPage(BasePage):
    def is_mappings_details_saved(self, name, dataset, feed, variable):    
        table_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((*MainPageLocators.mappings_details_savedpage_table)))
        rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        for row in rows:  
            # Get the columns
            col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]  
            col_variable = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]  
         etc...
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused about what you are trying to do. You waited for *all* `TD`s on the page in the first line (which seems odd)... why are you then waiting for all the `TR`s under some `TABLE` 3 lines down? My guess is that `table_id` is stale because you are using bad references in `*MainPageLocators`. Unless the table is getting loaded dynamically, you should be able to just wait for a single element on the page to load. Once it does, the entire DOM should be loaded. You could wait for the container `TABLE` if it has an ID, etc. Without more code or the relevant HTML, I'm not sure I can help you further.

Comment: I was waiting for all the columns to be loaded and then all the rows to be loaded.  I can then get values out of each column and rows.  This is the wrong way to do it.  I will try waiting for the table to be loaded then.  The table does have an ID.  Thank you for the sugesstion.

Comment: I tried waiting for the table to load.  I get the error Element is no longer valid.  My code is as follows: table_id = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body')))  and the next line is: rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

Comment: What is the syntax to wait for just the table to load please?

Comment: You look like you have the right syntax. I'm not sure why it's not working. Does the content in the table load late? Can you share the link to the page?

Comment: It is not a public facing url.  Website is installed locally onto the clients pc in Tomcat.  clients access the site by their machine name, port number http://machinename:8080/website

Comment: I have finally got it to work now.  Wait for just the table container like you said.  It is working now.  Thank you for your guidance to help me solve this.

Comment: Awesome! There's something satisfying about solving your own problems (even with a little help). I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

JeffC suggested to wait for just the table container to load.  No need to wait for cols and rows as well.  I have got it to work now.  I also put self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)in the base class - Here is the solution:

```
class BasePage(object):

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)

class MappingsPage(BasePage):
table_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((*MainPageLocators.mappings_details_savedpage_table)))
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:  
    # Get the columns
    col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]  
    col_variable = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]  
etc...
```

Comment: It's generally bad form to take an answer that someone else gave you, put it as your own answer, and then give yourself credit. If you want to post the final code, you can edit your question, put a divider line, and then explain here's the working solution.

Comment: I have added the divider line in my question and put the working solution there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the WebdriverWait on a long loop and chocking on it. The way I resolved was to create a utility function outside the loop.
In the loop call the function and pass parameters to it.

```
def try_path(driver,foo):
# this is an utility to circumvent the stale error
try:
    foo = WebDriverWait(driver).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "#yourtablehere")))
    return foo

except WebDriverException as e:
    return try_path(foo)
```

You may want to implement a counter just in case